# Can PHP tell when the browser goes away?

Tags: php

If I'm generating a stream of data to send out to a browser, and the user closes the browser, can I tell within PHP that I don't need to bother generating or sending the rest of the stream?  I'd like to insert something into this loop:

```
while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
   echo fgets($pipes[1]);
}
```

My fallback plan is to have the browser use a JavaScript onunload to hit another PHP page to kill the process that's generating the data, but it would be cleaner if PHP could tell when I'm echoing to nowhere.

Answer (score 10):

By default PHP will abort the script if the user navigates away. There are however times where you don't want this to happen so php has a config you set called `ignore_user_abort`.
http://php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

There's also a function called [register_shutdown_function()](https://www.php.net/register_shutdown_function) that is supposedly executed when execution halts. I've never actually used it, so I won't vouch for how well it works, but I thought I'd mention it for completeness.

Comment: Close but in this case he just wants to stop processing the data on user abort.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that script will automatically abort when loaded normally (No ajax). But if you want to implement some sort of long polling via php using xmlhttprequest I think you will have to do it with some sort of javascript because then php can't detect it. Also like to know the precise case.

Answer (score 0):

These answers pointed me towards what I was looking for.  The underlying process needed special attention to kill it.  I needed to jump out of the loop.  Thanks again, Stack Overflow.

```
 while (!feof($pipes[1]) && !connection_aborted())
 {
  echo fgets($pipes[1]);
 }

 if (connection_aborted())
 {
  exec('kill -4 '.$mypid);
 }
```